# web scraping: How to identify records in the database but removed on the Web

Tags: python, scrapy

Currently I'm using `Scrapy` to extract price from an online store. Say my first run extracted 100 products. After that, the store removed one product and added 2 new products. I'm wondering how to catch the removed product by comparing the new 101 products online and the old 100 products in my database?

For example, product 1 was $100 and I stored it into my database. Soon after product 1 was sold out and removed from the website. I wish somehow I could catch this change and update my the price of product 1 in my database.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe insert their name, ID or any other identifier the website uses in database too? Then when scraping, compare the identifier with the price to see if it exists or it it's price has changed.

Comment: @MohammadAmin, I stored ids and names. The thing is if a product is removed from the website, in the next scraping I won't get any information about this product.

Comment: As Mohammad stated, in order to compare the values you would need a name or identifier. If what you actually mean to do is determine when a product has changed i.e. be notified, then you would need to scrape at set intervals, every 30, 60, 90... 24hours etc... to catch the change.

Comment: @Harrison You can also add an is_removed field to your products and if it was removed, set is_removed to True.

Comment: are you asking for the actual comparison logic?

Comment: @MohammadAmin, how to know if a product is removed?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter, Yes, especially how to do it in `Scrapy`.

Comment: if so. `similar = [x for x in last_list_of_products if x in new_list_of_products]` will generate a list of items that are similar. `different = [x for x in last_list_of_products if x not in new_list_of_products]` will generate a list of items that were removed.

Comment: You don't need to use scrapy for list comprehension. Use Python 'list comprehension'. Lol

Comment: @TheLazyScripter, Where should I put this piece of code? I'm using `scrapy` to extract information, but I'm not familiar with its structure. I guess my question should be 'how to do it when using `scrapy`, rather than comparing 2 lists in Python'

Comment: How do you store your product data?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter using [`Scrapy piplines.py`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-mongodb). Similar to the example except I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out how to do this, so I will post it here if someone comes across this in the future.

The solution is to make a custom [extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html),

```
def __init__(self):
    scraped_item_list = []

def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    #connect signals

def spider_opened(self):
    #select a list of item_id (stored_item_list for example) in your database

def item_scraped(self, item):
    #append the item_id of the scraped item into scraped_item_list

def spider_closed(self):
    #compare stored_item_list with scraped_item_list to find any items which are in your database but not online anymore
    diff = set(stored_item_list) - set(scraped_item_list)
```